# Creating rigid grid structures for arranging video clips

Tags: software-recommendation, recommendation, technical

I'm quite new to video editing but I am not new to graphic design.
One of the most effective methods of organizing content in design is to use a grid. A grid lets things look good, stay consistent, and be predictable. I want to use a design grid to arrange video clips beside text and images.

[image: 12 column grid for graphic design with different element widths]

I wanted to know how to create a grid arrangement with columns, rows, gutters... I looked things up and all I could find were tutorials for resizing elements, without grids. If I were to start trying on my own I would go about it the following way: draw off-colour pixels in the corners of the areas where I want to put elements. It would probably take a very long time and be imprecise if I tried that though. Another idea I had was that I could use a green screen effect to create the boxes on the grid and then just place the images as the greenscreen content but that also feels like a hack and would surely end up losing parts of my clips at the edges. 
The way I imagine things I would have a nice "snap to grid" system that would let me resize clips to fill in grid spaces easily like in indesign/illustrator.

Through my workplace I have access to Sony Vegas but I own a mac so I could jump to any editor that would allow me to have this effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use markers and regions to note your columns.